# Property of $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis

I have a problem that I can't find proof anywhere.

Let $u\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ then $|u|\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$.

My question is: we know $u\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ then $u=0$ on boundary $\Omega$. How can we have $|u|=0$ on boundary $\Omega$?

Answer (score 0):

Observe $u \in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ if and only if $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and there is a sequence of functions $u_k$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ that have compact support in $\Omega$ and converge to $u$ in the $W^{1,p}$ norm.

Try to work through the following argument: if $u \in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$, then $|u| \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, and the corresponding sequence $\{u_k\}$ has the property that $|u_k| \to |u|$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. Since each $|u_k|$ has compact support, $|u| \in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ too.

Comment: Because $W_{0}^{1,p}\left(\Omega\right)=\overline{C_{0}^{\infty}\left(\Omega\right)}$ so we have $u_k \in C_{0}^{\infty}\left(\Omega\right)$ and $u_k$ converge to $u$ in $W^{1,p}\left(\Omega\right)$. But why $|u_k|$ has compact support. I don't understand "compact support". Can you explain more?